# Rails production environment breaks with cycle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Have a rails app (3.0.9) using HAML, local development server runs fine.  But when I run rails s -e production, my page gives this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `+@' for #<String:0x00000006331098>
```

The error says it is on this line (from the view, written in HAML):

```
%tr{:class=> cycle("even","odd")}
```

I'm not finding anything about why this is happening.  Please help.

Comment: Strange... I would try running it on a true production server such as `thin` and see what results.  You can push up to Heroku and try it out pretty easily.

Comment: I first found the problem on Heroku, then proceeded to test locally.

Comment: Try rewriting it to: `%tr{:class=>"#{cycle('even','odd')}"}`  Shouldn't make a difference, but your code also shouldn't be breaking as it is.

Comment: I tried     
    `-this_class = cycle("even", "odd")`  
then
    `%tr{:class=> this_class}`.  
That gave the same issue on the `-this_class =` line.

Comment: Might file a bug with Rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues

Comment: Before filing a bug, make sure you can reproduce it without HAML (ie. using ERB).

Comment: Is there a backtrace with the error?

Answer (score 1):

Does the `cycle` method do any sort of string concatenation?

I encountered this error recently during a code review.

The code was something like this:

`anObject.instance_method +string_var`

The `instance_method` was returning a string which was to be appended with the string value present in variable `string_var`.

Changing the code to this worked

`anObject.instance_method + string_var`  # Note the space after the +

Without space the `unary +` method is invoked on the string_var, but no `unary +` method is defined on the String class. Hence the exception.

Note that the `unary +` method is defined as `def +@`, hence the exception message says "Method `+@` not found".

This gist makes it clear : https://gist.github.com/1145457

Anyways, in your case, the method `cycle` (do not know whether it is defined by you or is part of a gem) is probably doing some string concatenation without proper spacing OR the exception backtrace is not pointing to the right line of code.

Hope this helps.